Windows Server 2019 netconnectionprofile missing
I have a Windows Server 2019 server accessible using RDP, however an error message states that there is no network connectivity. The network adapter profile is  public, and get-netconnectionprofile returns no results.
I used netsh winsock reset and netsh int ip reset without any success. The server has the latest NIC drivers and OS patch installed.
Is there something more that I can try?
